# org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'ReceiptTime'

Tags: xml, saxparseexception

I am trying to validate an xml file. Here is my xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

<xs:element name="EXTRACT">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="HEAD"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:element>

<xs:element name="HEAD">
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="RequestId" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="RequestsInBatch" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="PeriodDate" type="xs:date"/>
        <xs:element name="Type" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="StartDate" type="xs:date"/>
        <xs:element name="EndDate" type="xs:date"/>
        <xs:element name="PricingDate" type="xs:date"/>
        <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Here is my xml file

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<EXTRACT>
    <HEAD>
        <RequestId>1</RequestId>
        <RequestsInBatch>1,2</RequestsInBatch>
        <PeriodDate>2013-03-31</PeriodDate>
        <Type>Monthly</Type>
        <StartDate>2013-03-01</StartDate>
        <EndDate>2013-03-31</EndDate>
        <PricingDate>2013-03-29</PricingDate>
        <ReceiptTime>2013-04-02 12:30:00</ReceiptTime>
        <CreateTime>2013-04-02 16:00:00</CreateTime>
        <RecordCount>3</RecordCount>
        <ExceptionCount>1</ExceptionCount>
        <ExtractType>FLOWS</ExtractType>
        <ExtractCurrency>USD</ExtractCurrency>
    </HEAD>
</EXTRACT>
```

I don't care about the other tags, which I thought is indicated by

> ```
>    <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
> ```

But when I run in Java, I get the following error org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'ReceiptTime'

How can I validate the file so it ignores any element I don't declare in my xsd because I don't need them, but they are in the xml document anyway? I cannot control the contents of the xml document so I only need to focus on the data I want to extract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `processContents="lax"`.  The default is `strict` which means it can be any element so long as it is defined in your schema somewhere.

```
<xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0"/>
```

Checkout http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa547371(v=BTS.20).aspx.

Comment: Now I'm getting the following error: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'CreateTime'. No child element is expected at this point. I think it's saying that it can only allow one element. How do I make it accept more than one element?

Comment: Thanks for the info, that helps. Just a quick change, adding `maxOccurs="unbounded"` makes it work. So now it becomes:

`<xs:any processContents="lax" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>`